# C# Windsor.Castle exception could not instantiate ApplicatioName.MainWindow

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

When I'm trying to run an application that was developed in C# with the use of Windsor.Castle as DI I get an exception at startup and a long stacktrace. The last line is as follows:

`at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: ComponentActivator: could not instantiate ApplicationName.MainWindow`

One entry is from my application:

`at ApplicationName.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in D:\Path\ApplicationName\ApplicationName\App.xaml.cs:line 35`

That line reads as follows:

```cs
IShell<IMainWindow> mainProgram = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<IShell<IMainWindow>>();
```

`Bootstrapper` is a static class and `Container` a static method returning an instance of `IWindsorContainer`.

`IMainWindow` and `IShell` are registered in a class implementing `IWindsorInstaller`:

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IShell<IMainWindow>>().ImplementedBy<Shell>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<IMainWindow>().ImplementedBy<MainWindow>());
```

During development there were no issues regarding this error and on the development PC there are still no problems starting the application, the release binary runs without problems on development PC. But running the application on a different PC throws the exception.

`MainWindow.xaml.cs` only has a constructor with one parameter, the `IAbstractFactory`:

```cs
public MainWindow(IAbstractFactory factory)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            IMainViewModel mainViewModel = factory.Create<IMainViewModel>();
            this.Closing += mainViewModel.OnWindowClosing;
            this.DataContext = mainViewModel;
        }
```

I've tried to add a constructor without parameters to check if that works, but I get the same error.

Another attempt to solve the issue was to register with `IShell<MainWindow>>` instead of the interface. Works on develop machine, not on other machine.

Does someone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Is there any InnerException?

Comment: Of course, the inner exception. I'm not logging that right now. I'll take a look